# Dictionary within a list through a random data stream

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I was reading up about dictionaries from the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html) and came across the following scenario "

> - Let us say ,  that there exists a list : **`['x','y','z',.....]`**
> - I wish to generate a random data stream for each of the elements of the above list i.e. I want a `dictionary` like : **`{'x':[0,0,70,100,...] , 'y':[0,20,...] , ...}`**
> - I wish to do this task `dynamically` i.e. using a `loop`
> - At present I can do it `statically` i.e. by `hard-coding` it but that does not take me anywhere

**Can Someone help me out?**

`P.S. This is not a homework question`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random       # To generate your random numbers

LOW = 0             # Lowest random number
HIGH = 100          # Highest random number
NUM_RANDS = 5       # Number of random numbers to generate for each case

l = ['x', 'y', 'z'] # Your pre-existing list

d = {}              # An empty dictionary

for i in l:         # For each item in the list
    # Make a dictionary entry with a list of random numbers
    d[i] = [random.randint(LOW, HIGH) for j in range(NUM_RANDS)]

print d             # Here is your dictionary
```

If that confuses, you could replace the line `d[i] = [random...` with:

```
    # Create a list of NUM_RANDS random numbers
    tmp = []        
    for j in range(NUM_RANDS):   
        tmp.append(random.randint(LOW,HIGH))
    # Assign that list to the current dictionary entry (e.g. 'x')
    d[i] = tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random` and list comprehension :

```
>>> import random
>>> l=['x','y','z']
>>> r_list_length=[4,10,7]
>>> z=zip(r_list_length,l)
>>> {j:[random.randint(0,100) for r in xrange(i)]  for i,j in z}
{'y': [39, 36, 5, 86, 28, 96, 74, 46, 100, 100], 'x': [71, 63, 38, 11], 'z': [8, 100, 24, 98, 88, 41, 4]}
```

The range of `random.randint(0,100)` is optional you can change it !

Comment: Thanks @Kasra . Is there an easier way - say which does not use the  'easeness' , if such a word exists , of python to find the solution ?

Comment: @pranav welcome , mmm as i know i dont think there was a built-in or some module (if this is your mean) for such task !

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want a finite list of random values per key, or an infinite one, to be accessed by using a `for .. in` loop.

For the case of finite lists, the given answers are fine.

For the case of an "infinite" list per key, which doesn't really exist (unless you have an infinite amount of memory...), you should create a *generator* per key, and not a `list`.

Google [python generator](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=python%20generator) and you'll get all the needed documentation to get you started.